# get PIDs of processes from

Tags: process, kill

I have a path to an executable.
Assume I want to delete this file.

I need to find all processes launched using this file and kill them.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [lsof](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&sektion=8&manpath=linux) (list open files) could help you there.

To list all process that are using a specific file:

```
lsof /path/to/your/specific/file
```

Adding the `-t` option will only return PIDs that use the given file.

---

So, from there, you can kill all process that are using the specific file :

```
lsof -t /path/to/your/specific/file | while read PID; do kill -9 $PID; done
```

Or something like :

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t /path/to/your/specific/file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, assuming you are in the *nix world, you can use `fuser` command.

```
fuser <file_name>
```

will list you all process pids using the file. To kill processes accessing the file,

```
fuser -k <file_name>
```

Comment: only for your user id. need to run this as root to list all processes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to Windows you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645) from the Windows SysInternals suite