# How to get PID of an EXE file from Windows command line

Tags: pid

How do I get the PID of an EXE file from Windows command line?

I want to query the PID from the command line, rather than manually search in Task Manager.

I've found [something similar in nix](https://serverfault.com/questions/586569/get-pids-of-processes-from)

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell `Get-Process` can return the PID of running processes.

```perl
❯ Get-Process explorer

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
    135   218.04     218.04     140.12   34304   3 explorer

❯ (Get-Process explorer).Id
34304
```

[Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 0):

In unlikely event that you don't want PowerShell then there is also [tasklist](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist)